# Implementing base tests in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Imagine you want to build some `interface` for each test that will be implemented in the future.

For being more specific: Let's assume you want both methods to be included by each future test:

1. Loading inputs to dictionary\ list holding the tests inputs.=> this should be called once only
2. Iterating over all test inputs mentioned in `a` and doing some comparison between some logic on test input against the expected result.

How do you implement this behavior splitting to 2 pytest files:

1. base which will have this behavior above.
2. any additional tests that will be run will kind of inherit the behavior of 1 and will be able to add another specific tests in addition- if needed

Comment: You can load the basic part in a test fixture, and reference the fixture in each test. I'm not completey sure about the second part, but it sounds like you just want to parametrize the test - write the test logic and use `pytest.mark.parametrize` to provide different inputs. Actually maybe you don't need the fixture at all... depends on your concrete use case.

Comment: I think that these articles have information you are looking for: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html and https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/fixture.html